# How to send http from with POST method without URLEncoding in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to send some data to a server using POST in unity but because unity url-encodes the data when using `UnityWebRequest.Post()` I'm getting 404 error from server, so I want to constract request myself however I'm still getting same error.

the curl request is something like this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://[server url].com/api/v1/client/match/195' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0...' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'Data=1647396005200|7Q3E1dEzFnVDEdRtZbPEjBXkde+MGaWdzk9WJtmZF90='
```

I can send this data with .net without problem:

```
    private static async Task SendRequestAsync(string url)
    {
        string Json = $"{{\"Score\":10,\"Time\":10}}";
        string dataToSend = EncryptData(Json);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Data", dataToSend }
            };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", AccessToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        print(responseString);
    }
```

But I want to use UnityWebRequest to archive the same result but I'm getting server error. this is the code for UnityWebRequest.

```
            string Json = $"{{\"Score\":10,\"Time\":10}}";
            var dataToSend = EncryptData(Json);

            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("Data", dataToSend, Encoding.UTF8);

            var downloadHandlerRaw = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            //var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);

            request = new UnityWebRequest();
            request.url = url;
            request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
            request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(form.data);
            request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            request.SetRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
            request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", AccessToken);
            request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have tried so many things but I can't make it work. how can I fix it? any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well 404 is not an encoding issue. However the documentation for UnityWebRequest which is arguably the preferred choice handles data as you require.

Comment: @BugFinder yea I know 404 is not encoding issue, that is what server returns because it can't read the data.  returning 404 error is for security reasons.

Comment: Based on what you’re sending, it would be unusual that it returns a 404 for “security reasons”. Perhaps you can install fiddler and inspect the traffic?